# Using mysql 8 window functions

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

My salary table looks like this,

```
employeeId  Salary     salaryEffectiveFrom       
    19966   10000.00    2022-07-01
    19966   20000.00    2022-07-15
```

My role/grades table looks like this,

```
employeeId       grade      roleEffectiveFrom   
    19966       grade 3         2022-07-01  
    19966       grade 2         2022-07-10
```

I am trying to get the salary a grade is paid for by taking into account the effective date in both tables.

grade 3 is effective from 1-July-2022. grade 2 is effective from the 10th of July, implying grade 3 is effective till the 9th of July i.e. 9 days.
grade 2 is effective from 10-July-2022 onwards.

A salary of 10000 is effective from 1-July-2022 till 14-July-2022 as the salary of 20000 is effective from the 15th. Therefore grade 3 had a salary of 10000 for 9 days, grade 2 salary of 10000 for 4 days with grade 2 with a salary of 20000 from the 10th onwards. The role effectivefrom
date takes precedence over the salary effectivefrom date.

This query,

```
SELECT  er.employeeId,
        es.salary,
        `grade`,
        date(er.effectiveFrom) roleEffectiveFrom,
        date(es.effectiveFrom) salaryEffectiveFrom,
        DATEDIFF(LEAST(COALESCE(LEAD(er.effectiveFrom) 
OVER (PARTITION BY er.employeeId ORDER By er.effectiveFrom),
        DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(er.effectiveFrom),INTERVAL 1 DAY)),
        DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(er.effectiveFrom),INTERVAL 1 DAY)),
        er.effectiveFrom) as '#Days'  ,
        ROUND((salary * 12) / 365, 2) dailyRate
FROM EmployeeRole  er 
     join EmployeeSalary es ON (es.employeeId = er.employeeId)
      and er.employeeId = 19966
;
```

gives me the result set shown below,

```
employeeId  Salary      grade      roleEffectiveFrom    salaryEffectiveFrom    Days   dailyRate
    19966   10000.00    grade 3         2022-07-01          2022-07-01         0         328.77
    19966   20000.00    grade 3         2022-07-01          2022-07-15         9         657.53
    19966   10000.00    grade 2         2022-07-10          2022-07-01         0         328.77
    19966   20000.00    grade 2         2022-07-10          2022-07-15         22       657.53
```

grade3 is effective for 9 days in July so I want to get the total salary for those 9 days using a daily rate column, 328.77 * 9 = 2985.93 as a separate column but I am unable to do as I am getting the days for the wrong row i.e. 9 should be the result for the first row.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ix7yN4iD)

Comment: grade3 is effective for 9 days in July - why? published salary effective date shows grade 2 applies from 2022-07-01 ? Best publish source data and expected outcome as text.

Comment: because grade 2 is effective from 10th July. This employee has two grades effective from two different dates. The employee also has salary from two different effective dates. 10000 is effective from 1st July but as i want the grade to be taken into consideration this salary for grade 3 is effective till the 9th, whereas 20000 is effective from the 15th

Comment: Ok so what's the rule here - the roleEffectiveFrom  overrides the salaryEffectiveFrom in the 'previous record?

Comment: correct! the roleEffectiveFrom takes precedence as i want to get the salary based on how long a grade was effective for. That is why i am getting a daily rate for the salary instead of using the full figure given in the salary column

Comment: Can you provide a dbfiddle that matches the data give in your question? (This one had grades 'A' and 'B', and you are talking about 'grade3' ?)

Comment: @Luuk fiddle link updated

Comment: "grade3 is effective for 9 days in July".  This should mean that the line from 2022-07-01 to 2022-07-15 has to take into account two different salaries (10000 for the first 9 days, and 20000 for the rest of the days). ?

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if it were me, I'd generate a list containing an entry for each day with the effective grade and salary, and then just aggregate at the end.  Take a look at this fiddle:

https://dbfiddle.uk/4t2RW2M2

I've started with the aggregate query, just so we can see the output, then I break out pieces of the query to show intermediate outputs.  Here is an image of the final output and the query generating it:

[image]

```
SELECT grade, gradeEffective, salary, salaryEffective,
  min(dt) as startsOn, max(dt) as endsOn, count(*) as days,
  dailyRate, 
  sum(dailyRate) as pay
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT dt, grade, gradeEffective, salary, salaryEffective, 
    ROUND((salary * 12) / 365, 2) as dailyRate
  FROM (
    SELECT dts.dt, 
      first_value(r.grade)         OVER w as grade,
      first_value(r.effectiveFrom) OVER w as gradeEffective,
      first_value(s.salary)        OVER w as salary,
      first_value(s.effectiveFrom) OVER w as salaryEffective
    FROM (
      WITH RECURSIVE dates(n) AS (SELECT 0 UNION SELECT n + 1 FROM dates WHERE n + 1 <= 30)
      SELECT '2022-07-01' + INTERVAL n DAY as dt FROM dates
    ) dts
    LEFT JOIN EmployeeSalary s ON dts.dt >= s.effectiveFrom
    LEFT JOIN EmployeeRole r on dts.dt >= r.effectiveFrom
    WINDOW w AS (
      PARTITION BY dts.dt 
      ORDER BY r.effectiveFrom DESC, s.effectiveFrom DESC
      ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
    )
  ) z
) a GROUP BY grade, gradeEffective, salary, salaryEffective, dailyRate
ORDER BY min(dt);
```

Now, the first thing I've done is create a list of dates using a recursive CTE:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates(n) AS (SELECT 0 UNION SELECT n + 1 FROM dates WHERE n + 1 <= 30)
SELECT '2022-07-01' + INTERVAL n DAY as dt FROM dates
```

which produces a list of dates from July 1st to July 31st.

Take that list of dates and left join both of your tables to it, like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  WITH RECURSIVE dates(n) AS (SELECT 0 UNION SELECT n + 1 FROM dates WHERE n + 1 <= 30)
  SELECT '2022-07-01' + INTERVAL n DAY as dt FROM dates
) dts
LEFT JOIN EmployeeSalary s ON dts.dt >= s.effectiveFrom
LEFT JOIN EmployeeRole r on dts.dt >= r.effectiveFrom
```

with the dt greater than or equal to the effective dates.  Notice that after the 9th you start to get duplicate rows for each date.

[image]

We'll create a window to get the first values for grade and salary for each date, and we'll order first by role effectiveFrom and then salary effectiveFrom, to fulfil your priority condition.

```
SELECT dts.dt, 
  first_value(r.grade)         OVER w as grade,
  first_value(r.effectiveFrom) OVER w as gradeEffective,
  first_value(s.salary)        OVER w as salary,
  first_value(s.effectiveFrom) OVER w as salaryEffective
FROM (
  WITH RECURSIVE dates(n) AS (SELECT 0 UNION SELECT n + 1 FROM dates WHERE n + 1 <= 30)
  SELECT '2022-07-01' + INTERVAL n DAY as dt FROM dates
) dts
LEFT JOIN EmployeeSalary s ON dts.dt >= s.effectiveFrom
LEFT JOIN EmployeeRole r on dts.dt >= r.effectiveFrom
WINDOW w AS (
  PARTITION BY dts.dt 
  ORDER BY r.effectiveFrom DESC, s.effectiveFrom DESC
  ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
);
```

[image]

This is still going to leave us multiple entries for some dates, although they are duplicates, so let's use that output in a new query, using `DISTINCT` to leave us only one copy of each row and using the opportunity to add the daily rate field:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dt, grade, gradeEffective, salary, salaryEffective, 
  ROUND((salary * 12) / 365, 2) as dailyRate
FROM (
  SELECT dts.dt, 
    first_value(r.grade)         OVER w as grade,
    first_value(r.effectiveFrom) OVER w as gradeEffective,
    first_value(s.salary)        OVER w as salary,
    first_value(s.effectiveFrom) OVER w as salaryEffective
  FROM (
    WITH RECURSIVE dates(n) AS (SELECT 0 UNION SELECT n + 1 FROM dates WHERE n + 1 <= 30)
    SELECT '2022-07-01' + INTERVAL n DAY as dt FROM dates
  ) dts
  LEFT JOIN EmployeeSalary s ON dts.dt >= s.effectiveFrom
  LEFT JOIN EmployeeRole r on dts.dt >= r.effectiveFrom
  WINDOW w AS (
    PARTITION BY dts.dt 
    ORDER BY r.effectiveFrom DESC, s.effectiveFrom DESC
    ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
  )
) z;
```

This produces the deduplicated daily data

[image]

and now all we have to do is use aggregation to pull out the sums for each combination of grade and salary, which is the query that I started off with.

Let me know if this is what you were looking for, or if anything is unclear.

---

Since the start and end conditions weren't fleshed out in the question, I just created the date list arbitrarily.  It's not difficult to generate the list based on the first effectiveFrom in both tables, and here is an example that runs from that start date until current:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates(n) AS (
  SELECT min(effectiveFrom) FROM (
    select effectiveFrom from EmployeeRole UNION
    select effectiveFrom from EmployeeSalary
  ) z
  UNION SELECT n + INTERVAL 1 DAY FROM dates WHERE n <= now()
)
SELECT n as dt FROM dates
```

I also didn't handle for multiple employees, since there was only one given and I would just be guessing at the shape of the actual data.

Comment: i see where you are going with this, but i would not want to "hardcode" any date value into the query, i would be referring to this bit SELECT '2022-07-01', as the data could have any date values. Data i have provided here is just a snippet.

Comment: The concept works the same way if the date isn't hardcoded.  You would just have to add whatever logic is needed to determine the start date and either the end date or number of days in the list of dates.  I didn't because the start and end conditions given in the question were somewhat arbitrary, so I didn't spend any time on working out logic that might or might not address the actual requirements.  I also didn't add any logic to handle for multiple employees, because there was only one.  I figured the answer was long-winded enough already :)

Comment: I ended up going with this because this it ended up being more easily adaptable to changing requirements,Thank you

Comment: It's not the slickest, but it does have the advantage of being straightforward and easily adaptable.

Answer (score 2):

merge the 2 table dates, lead them then use correlated sub queries

```
with cte as
(
SELECT employeeid,effectivefrom from EMPLOYEEROLE
union  
select employeeid,effectivefrom from employeesalary
)
,cte1 as
(select employeeid,effectivefrom,
          coalesce(
            date_sub(lead(effectivefrom) over (partition by employeeid order by effectivefrom),interval 1 day) ,
            now())  nexteff
from cte
)
select *,
        datediff(nexteff,effectivefrom) + 1 diff, 
      (select grade from employeerole e where e.effectivefrom <= cte1.effectivefrom order by e.effectivefrom desc limit 1) grade,
      (select salary from employeesalary e where e.effectivefrom <= cte1.nexteff order by e.effectivefrom desc limit 1) salary
from cte1;


+------------+---------------------+---------------------+------+---------+--------+
| employeeid | effectivefrom       | nexteff             | diff | grade   | salary |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+------+---------+--------+
|      19966 | 2022-07-01 00:00:00 | 2022-07-09 00:00:00 |    9 | grade 3 |  10000 |
|      19966 | 2022-07-10 00:00:00 | 2022-07-14 00:00:00 |    5 | grade 2 |  10000 |
|      19966 | 2022-07-15 00:00:00 | 2022-10-08 08:51:49 |   86 | grade 2 |  20000 |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+------+---------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.003 sec)


with cte as
(
SELECT employeeid,effectivefrom from EMPLOYEEROLE
union  
select employeeid,effectivefrom from employeesalary
)
,cte1 as
(select cte.employeeid,effectivefrom,
          coalesce(
            date_sub(lead(effectivefrom) over (partition by employeeid order by effectivefrom),interval 1 day) ,
            last_day(maxdt))  nexteff
from cte
JOIN (select cte.employeeid,max(effectivefrom) maxdt from cte group by employeeid) c1
      on c1.employeeid = cte.employeeid
)
select *,
        datediff(nexteff,effectivefrom) + 1 diff, 
      (select grade from employeerole e where e.effectivefrom <= cte1.effectivefrom order by e.effectivefrom desc limit 1) grade,
      (select salary from employeesalary e where e.effectivefrom <= cte1.nexteff order by e.effectivefrom desc limit 1) salary
from cte1;

+------------+---------------------+---------------------+------+---------+--------+
| employeeid | effectivefrom       | nexteff             | diff | grade   | salary |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+------+---------+--------+
|      19966 | 2022-07-01 00:00:00 | 2022-07-09 00:00:00 |    9 | grade 3 |  10000 |
|      19966 | 2022-07-10 00:00:00 | 2022-07-14 00:00:00 |    5 | grade 2 |  10000 |
|      19966 | 2022-07-15 00:00:00 | 2022-07-31 00:00:00 |   17 | grade 2 |  20000 |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+------+---------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.004 sec)
```

Comment: this works well, Thank you! I want to limit nexteff to the last day of a given month so instead of using now() i tried last_day(effectivefrom). Logic being the last effectivefrom, 15-Jul-2022 in this example, nexteff for the same row should be last_day(effectivefrom) = 31-Jul-22 making diff to be 17. Would that entail too much of a change to this query ?

Comment: Not much of a change see edit

Comment: Brilliant! I am giving it a go on an enhancement to this where an employee exit date is involved i.e. should an employee leave on a date that falls between effectivefrom & nexteff i will need to deduct the days from the diff column. E.g. Employee left on 20-Jul-22 i need to take 6 days off the 17. I tried via a join on the table that holds the exit date field and added a case statement but i am not quite there yet https://dbfiddle.uk/xar1F_Ae

Answer (score 1):

You can start adding two new columns (i.e. `tmpFrom` and `tmpTo`), which should give the correct dates which are needed to calculate the 9 Days.

```sql
SELECT
    er.employeeId,
    es.salary,
    `grade`,
    date(er.effectiveFrom) roleEffectiveFrom,
    date(es.effectiveFrom) salaryEffectiveFrom,
    DATEDIFF(LEAST(COALESCE(LEAD(er.effectiveFrom) 
                                 OVER (PARTITION BY er.employeeId ORDER By er.effectiveFrom),
                         DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(er.effectiveFrom),INTERVAL 1 DAY)),
                         DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(er.effectiveFrom),INTERVAL 1 DAY)),
                er.effectiveFrom) as '#Days'  ,
    ROUND((salary * 12) / 365, 2) dailyRate,
    date(er.effectiveFrom) tmpFrom,
    (select e2.effectiveFrom 
           from EmployeeRole e2
           where e2.employeeId = er.employeeId and e2.effectiveFrom > er.effectiveFrom
           order by e2.effectiveFrom
           limit 1) as tmpTo
FROM EmployeeRole  er 
join EmployeeSalary es ON (es.employeeId = er.employeeId)
      and er.employeeId = 19966
order by er.effectiveFrom
;
```

In above query I used a sub-select, which might hurt performance.  You can study [Window Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html), and check if there is a function which suits your needs better than this sub-query.

It's up to you to calculate the number of days between those two columns, but you should also *solve* the `NULL` value which should be end of month (But I am not sure if I remember your problem correctly...)

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/HspZzdKk)